# how to get unique value

Tags: r

I want to know the number of unique values, number of 2, 3 or more values

```
x
  name   var
1    a  abc1
2    b  abc1
3    c  abc2
4    d  abc2
5    e  abc2
6    f accd1
7    g baac1
```

---

```
y <- data.frame(table(x$var))
y
   Var1 Freq
1  abc1    2
2  abc2    3
3 accd1    1
4 baac1    1
```

---

if using `table()`, I can see how many of them `Var1` have.
BUT, What I want to know is.. how many unique value's got. (and 2, 3 or more)

like this.

```
unique value : 2   #(accd1, baac1)
     2 value : 1   #(abc1)
   3 or more : 1   #(abc2)
```

Comment: You may need to call `table` on the output

Answer (score 0):

using `tidyverse` functions, you can try something like

```
df %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  mutate( cnt = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(cnt) %>%
  mutate(freq = n()) %>%
  select(cnt, freq) %>%
  unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
freq <- data.frame(table(x$var))$Freq
table(ifelse(freq >= 3, "3 and more", freq))

> table(ifelse(freq >= 3, "3 and more", freq))

1          2 3 and more 
2          1          1
```

Or with the `dplyr` library :

```
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  count(var) %>% 
  mutate(values = ifelse(n >= 3, "3 and more", n)) %>%
  count(values)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  values        nn
  <chr>      <int>
1 1              2
2 2              1
3 3 and more     1
```